# Copying features from a shapefile into an existing feature class using python (ArcMap 10.5)?

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy, arcmap

I have a shapefile which contains some features and I need to copy these features and paste them into an EXISTING feature class using arcpy. I have tried the (arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(..)) but it seems it is used only to copy data from a shapefile to a NEW feature class.

```
import arcpy
input_ShapeFile = "C:\Users\Moh\Desktop\file.shp"
output_FeatureClass = "C:\Users\Moh\Desktop\Data.mdb\fc"
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(input_ShapeFile, output_FeatureClass)

...ERROR 000725: Output Feature Class: Dataset "C:\Users\Moh\Desktop\Data.mdb\fc" already exists. Failed to execute (CopyFeatures).
```

Comment: I think questions about ArcPy are best researched/asked at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Ok thanks PolyGeo.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Append` tool:

```
arcpy.Append_management(input_ShapeFile, input_FeatureClass, "NO_TEST")
```

Tool documentation: [Append (Data Management)—ArcMap | Documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/append.htm)

What you can do in addition, is to use the `SearchCursor` and the `InsertCursor`. By doing this you can put the Shapefile geometries into the Feature Class, and if you know that the fields of both are the same then you can also keep the tabular data:

```
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(output_FeatureClass, ['Shape@'] + [fields]) as insert:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(input_ShapeFile, ['Shape@'] + [fields]) as search:
        for row in search:
            insert.insertRow(row)
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76137784/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).